mysql2 module not found error in next application
I am using mysql2 in my next application. Some times it throws error MODULE not found in ./node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:18:1
it works some time & not always. I tried many things. Still i didnot get the solution.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your source code as a working minimal reproducible example, which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Please add some code regarding the connection.js file & also additional error details.
